# Wso2esb - lower memory performance

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.7.0.I'm facing problem of memory overflow.Actually if their is less load on system then it works fine but as per load increases the system get slower.upto 80 to 90% system handles itself somehow but above than that it can't allocate the new objects.After that it gives timeout error or server get down.i have to restart the system.

For the performance improvement i have tried **thrashing**.It helps me littlebit but not that much..still system causes problem.Is their any suggestion to improve system performance?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB document contains some performance tuning parameters. Did you go though them. Please find it from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Performance+Tuning) for ESB 4.7.0.  If it is OOM issue, Sometime you may have not increase the memory foot print of ESB. You can increase it using following parameters in `wso2server` script file.

`-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Comment: thanks for reply @Asela : I have tried this too..but didn't make that much help.Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: What kind of processing happening in ESB.. any special things to mention? It is possible for you to analyze the memory growth of ESB server using jconsole or jprofiler ? Then it would be easy to figure out.